# Yii2 date formatter not working in active form

Tags: php, yii2

I setup in config file date format as :

```
'dateFormat' => 'yy-MM-dd',
```

but I can't find the way to get dates in this format in active form :
I tried :

```
<?= $form->field($model,
    'mydate':date,
```

but this gives error
Any help would be nice :)

Comment: you want format for selection or validation.you use jquery date picker

Answer (score 0):

You must **replace date into needed format by using DateTime**.

For example, if you have data in Unix format and want to convert to 'd-M-Y':

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$this->date)->format('d-m-Y')
```

If you always need this conversion, you can create a getter function in model:

```
public function getDateInFormat()
{
  return \DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$this->date)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

And the in view:

```
<?= $form->field($model,$model->dateInFormat); ?>
```

Comment: Ok I hear you - So what you say is that there is no way to setup something one time for all ? Each time I am handling a date I need to do conversion ? And the setup in datepicker is for nothing ? This is bad news !

Comment: Yeah, i know) But it is common practice

Answer (score 0):

Here `dateFormat` is a property of the `\Yii::$app->formatter` component.

In order to explicitly use this setting you should use **formatter**

`\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($date)`

or **i18n** component

`\Yii::t('app', 'The date is: {0,date}', $date);`

Also this option is used as default `format` in [date validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#date).

So all you need is to add the `date` rule (in `rules` function of your model):

```
['mydate', 'date']
```

And then you can just add in your view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mydate', [])->input('text', []); ?>
```

In order to work with database you can either manually convert date attribute to/from db format (for example overriding `beforeSave` and `afterFind` if you work with ActiveRecord) or use [timestampAttribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator.html#$timestampAttribute-detail) and [timestampAttributeFormat](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-datevalidator.html#$timestampAttributeFormat-detail) in `date` validator.

For advanced cases you can use something like [yii2-datecontrol](http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol).